# Gesture Detection within a method

Tags: android, gesture, gesturedetector

Hey all so I'm running into an issue where I need to be able to use a gesture detector within a method so I can call upon a method within said method I'll paste the code but basically it can't reach my inner statement therefore it's throwing an error!

```
private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new MyGestureDetector());
    gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    };
```

Then when I go to call the class to use the gesture detector:

```
public void notification() {
    final AchievementUnlocked achievementUnlocked = new AchievementUnlocked(MainActivity.this)
    achievementUnlocked.getAchievementView().setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
    class MyGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            try {
                if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                    return false;
                // left to right swipe
                if(e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                achievementUnlocked.dismiss();
                }
                // right to left swipe
                else if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // nothing
            }
            return false;
        }
```

If I do this i get an error in this part of the code Cannot Resolve Symbol 'MyGestureDetector':

```
 gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new MyGestureDetector());
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare a regular Java class inside of a method. Move `MyGestureDetector` outside of the `notification()` method.

Comment: Okay and I did that but now I can't access a method inside of the Notification method?

Comment: @SkylerMartin: There is no "method inside of the Notification method". I presume that you are referring to `achievementUnlocked`. Perhaps `MyGestureDetector` should hold the `AchievementUnlocked` instance in a field. Or, perhaps `MyGestureDetector` should do something else, like post a message on an event bus (e.g., greenrobot's EventBus), which in turn is picked up by the `AchievementUnlocked` instance elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Move `MyGestureDetector` outside and change method that you call inside it (like `achievementUnlocked.dismiss();`) to be static

Comment: I can't make it static or else my variables all get an error!